# No response from Service and BroastReciver running on App install

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

There are many duplicate related to mine but mostly have not given answer regarding to my query: I want to make only service based App not even single activity.I have read tutorials and took help from  stackoverflow. I have implement in this way

1. Made BroadcastReciver
2. Delcared BroadcastReciver in Manifest
3. started service in BroadcastReciver

**My problem:**

1. My broadcastReciver doesn't even start.and also no service  started 
       by it
2. It doesn't show me any Toast nether Log
3. Please help me figure 
       out where i m making mistake

Manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".BroadcastReciverOnInstalltion" >
            <intent-filter  >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH" />

                <data android:scheme="com.example.latest.sampleaudio" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

BroastcatReciver

```
public class BroadcastReciverOnInstalltion extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

                Log.i("installeded", "installeded");
                Toast.makeText(context, "...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                context.startService(new Intent(context, ServiceMusic.class));


    }
};
```

Comment: you cannot do what you are trying to do

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: can you please read the question that was already answered